# Jenkins vs SonarQube : Run with specific JDK

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a project which is built and compiled with JDK 1.7 and Sonarqube 6.0 which only runs with JDK 1.8. 
On Jenkins dashboard, I set Goal: **:org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:LATEST:sonar** and on wrapper.conf on sonarqube folder, i changed **wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java**, Jenkins JDK is set 1.7....but Sonar doesn't work with JDK 1.8.
Please help give me advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

The solution was to set JDK8 to be used in the Job-Configuration in Jenkins and set JDK7 to be used for the compilation of the sources, the test-sources and surefire plugin.

Something like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <testSource>1.7</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.7</testTarget>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac</executable>
                <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>C:\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\javac</executable>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                        <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvm>C:\java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java</jvm>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If it works for you, you can set the Path to the JDK in settings.xml and use that setting in you pom.xml so each environment/developer can use their own JDK.

```
<profile>
  <id>jdk7</id>
  <properties>
    <JDK_1_7_HOME>C:\java\jdk1.7.0_25</JDK_1_7_HOME>
  </properties>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
</profile>
```

And your pom.xml

```
...
    <executable>${JDK_1_7_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
...
```